# How to prevent the peek method from moving the read cursor ahead?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I'm writing a method to split a text file. It has two options,

- Split a file blindly (split the file according to the bytes given)
- Split a file by preserving lines (if the last line in the splitted file is not whole, then it's moved to the next split)

The code for preserving lines is as follows:

```
file.rewind # `file` is a File object with proper modes passed
lines = file.each_line

until file.eof?
  tfile.truncate(0) # `tfile` is a temporary File object which will be given to the block passed

  while tfile.size + lines.peek.size <= size
    tfile << lines.next
    tfile.flush
  end

  file_count += 1
  yield(tfile, file_count)
end
```

Now the problem is that if there only remains one line in the last split, then the iteration won't run, because `peek` moves the cursor to the end of file in the second last iteration and therefore condition for the last iteration of the `unless` produces a `true` value and the loop exits.

How to solve this issue of the cursor moving to ***eof***?

I'm thinking of moving the cursor back one line before every `next`. If there is a better option, then suggest it.

Comment: Also, there is no one single `unless` in the code you posted.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Ruby. I encountered the same issue earlier today and have reported it on their bug tracker here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15001

Comment: Yeah it's a bug. Because it gives a different result with normal strings.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerator#peek`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) does not move the internal position of the `Enumerator` forward. But if the position is already at the end, `StopIteration` is raised. The thing is you don’t need to `peek` at all.

That would be the proper way to solve the issue (the code is untested, but it should work):

```
file.rewind
tfile.truncate(0)

total_files =
  file.each_line.with_object(file_count: 0) do |line, acc|
    if tfile.size + line.size <= size
      tfile << line
      tfile.flush
    else
      acc[:file_count] += 1
      yield(tfile, acc[:file_count])

      tfile.truncate(0)
      tfile << line
      tfile.flush
    end
  end[:file_count]
yield(tfile, total_count)
```

Comment: Consider the 2-tweak `file.each_line.with_object(file_count: 0)...`.

Comment: This algorithm doesn't `yield` the last of the split file. You have to call `yield` after `each_line` is over. This is why I went with the other approach.

Comment: Also, I know that `peek` doesn't increment the internal counter. What I'm saying is that it increments the 'cursor' which reads the file. Execute this in IRB: [peek-method-file-issue](https://pastebin.com/S9xPJFYs)

Comment: @radiantshaw you don’t need `eof?` at all, you are mixing concepts: `each_line` is an enumerator over strings, it deals with the underlying IO device internally and it does not expect you to intervene this with low-level calls.